# Fetch Airtable image url in a array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was looking into the Airtable API, and I looked into the section "list records", I can see the sample code in Javascript, and some of the fields I have looked into, it only works on the 'text' or string field type.

```
eachPage(function page(records, fetchNextPage) {
    records.forEach(function(record) {
        console.log('Retrieved', record.get('Name'));
    });
```

Then I tried adding the "profile photo" field, but knowing the field is actually a array type because there are separate URLS for different image sizes in a array. Simply what I did is this

```
eachPage(function page(records, fetchNextPage) {
    records.forEach(function(record) {
        console.log('Retrieved', record.get('Profile Photo'));
    });
```

I tested in a playcode.io playground and came out as this:

```
Retrieved (1) [{...}]
Retrieved (1) [{...}]
Retrieved (1) [{...}]
```

Is there a way to get a item in a array field in this?

Comment: What do you get when you try something like, `console.log(record.get('Profile Photo'), null, 2)`  ?

Comment: nope. it comes out to `(1) [{...}] null 2`